# Slack API - input box with type password to hide the information

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

Is there anyway to hide the text entered in input box field (similar to HTML password type)?

Answer (score 1):

Although all user data is handled with security controls, Slack API currently doesn't support data masking or hiding sensitive data from the screen. I doubt this is a feature that will be added soon. You can find more on this discussion [here](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/607)